# How to apply a continous color ramp to a straight line in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-hline, geom-vline, geom-segment

I have would like to apply a continous color ramp to a vertical line in ggplot2. My plot is below. I have applied the continous color ramp to the `geom_line()` element, while the horizontal lines represent the limits of the range covered by the color ramp and are appropriately colored. I would like the vertical line on the left side to show the full range of the color ramp between the two horizontal lines.

I tried `geom_segment(aes(color=dwsTempOutC))` (dwsTempOutC is my y axis variable) but as you can see in the image it only applied a single color to the line.

I imagine I could achieve a continous color ramp by generating a series of short line segments and applying a discrete color from the ramp to each, but I'm hoping there is a less hacky way to do it.

[image]

Comment: It would be eaiser to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: This said: Basically one option to achieve your desired result would be `ggforce::geom_link`

Comment: `geom_link` seems like it would get the job done but does ggplot2 not a have a way to do this internally? I would prefer not to use additional packages unless ggplot2 is unable to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when using `geom_segment` then, well, there is only one segment. However, besides `ggforce::geom_link` you could achieve the same result using `geom_line`:

Using some fake data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 100),
  y = sin(seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 100))
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = -.5, y = seq(-1, 1, length.out = 100))) +
  scale_color_viridis_c()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions work but the geom_line() approach is great because it doesn't require any other packages.

Answer (score 2):

As @stefan already suggests in the comments we could use `geom_link2` from `ggforce` package, here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_link2(aes(x = 5, y = mpg, colour = mpg), size=2)+
  scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=mid, low="green", mid="white",
                          high="red")
```

[image]