# scale_color_gradient for geom_curve in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Currently I have a dataframe consisting of several flight as such

[image: dataframe]

Using ggplot as shown below, I have managed to plot the flight path from origin to destination however cannot seem to change the path line to gradient colour that can visualise the flight from origin to destination.

Do advise as from my understanding, ggplot colour must be reliant on a variable.

```
q4c%>% 
  mutate(TailNum = factor(x=TailNum, levels=c("N351UA","N960DL","N524", "N14998", "N355CA","N711UW", "N587AA", "N839UA","N941CA","N516UA"))) %>%
  ggplot() + usMap2 +
  geom_curve(aes(x=OriginLong, y=OriginLat, xend=DestLong, yend=DestLat, size=TotalDelay,color=TailNum),
             curvature=0.2)+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.02, 0.5))+
  geom_point(aes(x=OriginLong, y=OriginLat), 
             size=0.02) +
  geom_point(aes(x=DestLong, y=DestLat), 
             size=0.02) +
  facet_wrap(~TailNum)
```

[image: Current Plot]

edit:

I have tried ggforce::geom_link however it only shows solid colors instead of gradient as i added dummy sequence of 0,1 to get the color contrast

```
structure(list(Year = c(2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L
), Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), DayofMonth = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), DepTime = c(1022L, 1025L, 1037L, 1054L, 1110L, 
1111L), ArrTime = c(1527L, 1057L, 1209L, 1219L, 1454L, 1409L), 
    DepDelay = c(3L, 0L, -10L, -1L, 65L, -2L), ArrDelay = c(6L, 
    -3L, -11L, -27L, 52L, -8L), TotalDelay = c(9L, -3L, -21L, 
    -28L, 117L, -10L), TailNum = c("N351UA", "N524", "N14998", 
    "N941CA", "N355CA", "N587AA"), Origin = c("DEN", "PHX", "LBB", 
    "LGA", "SLC", "DFW"), Dest = c("CLT", "BUR", "IAH", "GSO", 
    "STL", "IND"), AirportOrigin = c("Denver Intl", "Phoenix Sky Harbor International", 
    "Lubbock International", "LaGuardia", "Salt Lake City Intl", 
    "Dallas-Fort Worth International"), OriginLong = c(-104.6670019, 
    -112.0080556, -101.8227778, -73.87260917, -111.9777731, -97.0372
    ), OriginLat = c(39.85840806, 33.43416667, 33.66363889, 40.77724306, 
    40.78838778, 32.89595056), AirportDest = c("Charlotte/Douglas International", 
    "Burbank-Glendale-Pasadena", "George Bush Intercontinental", 
    "Piedmont Triad International", "Lambert-St Louis International", 
    "Indianapolis International"), DestLong = c(-80.94312583, 
    -118.3584969, -95.33972222, -79.9372975, -90.35998972, -86.29438417
    ), DestLat = c(35.21401111, 34.20061917, 29.98047222, 36.09774694, 
    38.74768694, 39.71732917), id = 1:6, seqnum = c(1, 6, 1, 
    6, 1, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

dataframe

```
q4cc%>% 
  ggplot() + usMap2 +
  geom_link2(aes(x=OriginLong, y=OriginLat, size=TotalDelay, colour=seqnum))+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.02, 1))+
  scale_color_gradient(name="Journey Path", high="red", low="blue")+
  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0.03,0.3))+
  geom_point(aes(x=OriginLong, y=OriginLat), 
             colour="red",
             size=0.02) +
  facet_wrap(~TailNum)
```

[New Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9RST.png)

Comment: Do you mean you want the lines to change colour, as in each line starts one color then gradually changes to another colour? This is not natively possible in ggplot, though there are some add on packages that can achieve this.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes correct thats what i meant, do you know what package it is ? I have tried like adding id number and sequence but the result isn't what i want.

Comment: You could look at `geom_link` from the `ggforce` package. Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226957/how-to-apply-a-continous-color-ramp-to-a-straight-line-in-ggplot2) previous Stack Overflow question

Comment: @AllanCameron i have tried your suggestion however it only display solid color instead of the gradient color which i wanted to show for origin to destination. Do advice.

Comment: I can't really show you how to use it on your data set because I don't have your data set. Can you make your example reproducible by showing how you are getting `q4c` and `usMap2` in a way that I can get them too?

Comment: @AllanCameron my q4c is the screenshot at the start. There are 1000+ observation thus i only post a single row just to show what variables i have.
USmap is basically the usmap library and the code is as follow `usMap2 <- borders("state",colour="grey", fill="white")`

Comment: @AllanCameron i added the list in the question above if it helps.